# convert an integer to a roman numera

Tags: python

I tried to convert an integer to a roman numeral by using class. Below is the code that I found on the website, but I can't clearly understand how the following code works. Can someone helps me to break and explains it? Thanks

```
class py_solution:
def int_to_Roman(self, num):
    val = [
        1000, 900, 500, 400,
        100, 90, 50, 40,
        10, 9, 5, 4,
        1
        ]
    syb = [
        "M", "CM", "D", "CD",
        "C", "XC", "L", "XL",
        "X", "IX", "V", "IV",
        "I"
        ]
    roman_num = ''
    i = 0
    while  num > 0:
        for _ in range(num // val[i]):
            roman_num += syb[i]
            num -= val[i]
        i += 1
    return roman_num
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly, right?

Comment: Have you traced through it with sample values?  As long as the number remaining is greater than the next symbol, it keeps adding that symbol until it goes below.  It's basically how you would do it as a human.  For 2021, you'd add two Ms, and be left with 21.  You'd add two Xs, and be left with 1.  So, MMXXI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll explain by "running" the code "line-by-line".Let's take the number 8 as example.

```
8 is obviously > 0. # We are now inside the while loop

i = 0 # You got a iterator starting with 0.
```

Then you go to a loop for with range equals to (8//var[0]) wich is equals to (8//1000), wich is equals to zero.
Since you have zero you don't go to the next 2 lines. Then the iterator is incremented `i+=i+1`. This process is repeated until you get a range greater than zero  (it happens when i=10). Now, 8//5 is equals to 1 and you go to the next two lines.

```
roman_num += syb[10] #get us roman_num ='V'
```

and

```
num -= val[10] #get us num = 3.
```

After that 'i' is incremented  to 11. This make the range of loop for zero again and the 'i' is incremented to 12. This make the range of the loop for go to 3.Then the loop for concatenate 'I' in the roman_num 3 times decrementing num each time by one resulting in `num = 0` returning the correct answer of `'VIII'`.

Comment: your explanation helped me a lot. Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

It's like the cashier giving you change. Imagine coins come in M for 1000, CM for 900, D for 500, etc. Given a value, you first divide it by 1000 and give out the "M" coins, then divide the remainder by 900 and give out the "CM" coins, etc.

In your code, the while loop cycles through the different coins, and the for loop counts how many of each type of coin to give out.